# Prevent bootstrap modal from being pushed when a dropdown list appears

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap's modal for displaying a dropdown menu containing a list of countries. There is an issue when the list shows up as it is much longer than the window (it is worth mentioning I am working on a browser extension).

[image: no extra styling]

Since I am using Vue.js, my code is:

```
<template>
  <div class="modal fade" id="chooseCountry">
    <div class="absolute justify-content-center modal-dialog-centered modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="mb-2">How can I prevent that from happening?</div>
          <v-select label="name" :options="countries"></v-select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

...which is a generic Bootstrap template but with added vSelect - a [select/dropdown component](https://vue-select.org/). I tried adding `overflow-y: hidden;` to `#chooseCountry` and despite hiding the outer scrollbar, the left gap would still appear every time the little arrow was clicked(i.e. dropdown was appearing)

[image: Modal with added overflow-y:hidden; to the outer part]

---

**The modal has the same width as the parent and the issue appears with the outer scrollbar. It adjusts its width such that the scrollbar can fit on the right (1st image), creating a whitespace on the left too, matching the right gap. The problem is, when a scrollbar is hidden, it still adds the gap on the left-hand side anyway (2nd image)..**

---

So is there a way to force the modal to keep its original width? Alternatively, what could also work is another dropdown list with a dedicated input field for searching. I noticed I used vSelect since it was quicker for me to use a pre-made solution but if it would solve my issue, then I am keen on removing it :-).

Any help will be highly appreciated and sorry if a similar post has been already posted but I found nothing that could help me and my program, especially because it is a browser extension...

If I missed any code that might be relevant please let me know and I will provide it happily.

Comment: I wasn't entirely clear on what the problem is. Here's my attempt at a summary so folks can understand better; please correct where I'm wrong and clarify where possible... "When a user clicks to open my dropdown list, the width of the list increases unexpectedly and extra whitespace appears inside the container, shifting all the list items to the right. In contrast, with a short list (only a few items), there is no increase in container width and no horizontal shifting of list items. I have a long list but I want the 'short list' behavior."

Comment: Hi! Well yes and no.. I would like it to 'behave as a short list' but since I want to allow to choose from the list of all countries, it will never be short unless a person starts typing a country's name(which will shorten/filter the list but the uneven placement would remain as it is).
I updated the description and hopefully it is a bit more explicit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh okay, my bad - the solution is easier than I thought.

Apparently Bootstrap offers a [special Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content), which solves the issue:

---

[image: A solution to my issue]

---

Combining it with `overflow-y:hidden;` does everything I wanted.

Comment: I will leave this question/answer just in case someone cannot find it too.